# A woman is forced to grow black wings, but it's not the Black Wings series

Tags: story-identification, books

The young woman was a skilled diver for gems or similar held within fish mouths. An auspicious change was signalled when she found two within the same fish.

A series of circumstances forces her into a position to grow wings, a process that takes three days. It is painful. She knows that having these wings will curse her, and she will be unable to ever stop flying as she'll now be ceaselessly pursued by an incarnation of something. Death? Who knows?

For a time she takes refuge with an entity of water, as she'll be safe from pursuit there. The entity loves her, but she feels trapped, and is unhappy around all of the water her wings prevent her from swimming in.

Fairly certain this was the first in a series.

Answer (score 5):

[*Racing the Dark*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1107632.Racing_the_Dark) by Alaya Dawn Johnson. First in the [*Spirit Binders*](https://www.goodreads.com/series/43892-spirit-binders) series.

I found this via a Goodreads "Find this book" [question](https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/17539077-solved-ya-dark-fantasy-book-2010-or-earlier-magic-fish-with-jewels-g) that matched in the details. Here are excerpts from the Goodreads request post:

> [Searching for book:] magic fish with jewels, girl grows wings.
>
> It starts out with our protagonist, a teenage girl, waking up to
>   discover she's had her first period, and in her culture, that means
>   she has to wash it off in the ocean when she dives for a fish that
>   gives away a jewel for whatever reason, but she gets two
>   jewels,because the fish is dying.
>
> Later, something weird happens, I think the girl has an unspoken love
>   for some religious novice, and then spends a night on an altar growing
>   wings and then flies off to save the world?

And from Goodreads reviews:

> Lana meets her true [love], and he spirits her away to his stronghold.
>
> [She is] seeking comfort with the water guardian.

[image: Racing the Dark front cover]